# Scalaz state monad examples

Tags: scala, scalaz, state-monad

I haven't seen many examples of the scalaz state monad. There is [this example](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.2/doc.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleState.scala.html) but it is hard to understand and there is only one [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562850/basic-scalaz-state-question) on stack overflow it seems.

I'm going to post a few examples I've played with but I would welcome additional ones. Also if somebody can provide example on why `init`, `modify`, `put` and `gets` are used for that would be great.

*Edit: [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg3Uv_YWJqI) is an awesome 2 hours presentation on the state monad.*

Answer (score 83):

I assume, *scalaz 7.0.x* and the following imports (look at answer history for *scalaz 6.x*):

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

The state type is defined as `State[S, A]` where `S` is type of the state and `A` is the type of the value being decorated. The basic syntax to create a state value makes use of the `State[S, A]` function:

```
// Create a state computation incrementing the state and returning the "str" value
val s = State[Int, String](i => (i + 1, "str"))
```

To run the state computation on a initial value:

```
// start with state of 1, pass it to s
s.eval(1)
// returns result value "str"

// same but only retrieve the state
s.exec(1)
// 2

// get both state and value
s(1) // or s.run(1)
// (2, "str")
```

The state can be threaded through function calls. To do this instead of `Function[A, B]`, define `Function[A, State[S, B]]]`. Use the `State` function...

```
import java.util.Random
def dice() = State[Random, Int](r => (r, r.nextInt(6) + 1))
```

Then the `for/yield` syntax can be used to compose functions:

```
def TwoDice() = for {
  r1 <- dice()
  r2 <- dice()
} yield (r1, r2)

// start with a known seed 
TwoDice().eval(new Random(1L))
// resulting value is (Int, Int) = (4,5)
```

Here is another example. Fill a list with `TwoDice()` state computations.

```
val list = List.fill(10)(TwoDice())
// List[scalaz.IndexedStateT[scalaz.Id.Id,Random,Random,(Int, Int)]]
```

Use sequence to get a `State[Random, List[(Int,Int)]]`. We can provide a type alias.

```
type StateRandom[x] = State[Random,x]
val list2 = list.sequence[StateRandom, (Int,Int)]
// list2: StateRandom[List[(Int, Int)]] = ...
// run this computation starting with state new Random(1L)
val tenDoubleThrows2 = list2.eval(new Random(1L))
// tenDoubleThrows2  : scalaz.Id.Id[List[(Int, Int)]] =
//   List((4,5), (2,4), (3,5), (3,5), (5,5), (2,2), (2,4), (1,5), (3,1), (1,6))
```

Or we can use `sequenceU` which will infer the types:

```
val list3 = list.sequenceU
val tenDoubleThrows3 = list3.eval(new Random(1L))
// tenDoubleThrows3  : scalaz.Id.Id[List[(Int, Int)]] = 
//   List((4,5), (2,4), (3,5), (3,5), (5,5), (2,2), (2,4), (1,5), (3,1), (1,6))
```

Another example with `State[Map[Int, Int], Int]` to compute frequency of sums on the list above. `freqSum` computes the sum of the throws and counts frequencies.

```
def freqSum(dice: (Int, Int)) = State[Map[Int,Int], Int]{ freq =>
  val s = dice._1 + dice._2
  val tuple = s -> (freq.getOrElse(s, 0) + 1)
  (freq + tuple, s)
}
```

Now use traverse to apply `freqSum` over `tenDoubleThrows`. `traverse` is equivalent to `map(freqSum).sequence`.

```
type StateFreq[x] = State[Map[Int,Int],x]
// only get the state
tenDoubleThrows2.copoint.traverse[StateFreq, Int](freqSum).exec(Map[Int,Int]())
// Map(10 -> 1, 6 -> 3, 9 -> 1, 7 -> 1, 8 -> 2, 4 -> 2) : scalaz.Id.Id[Map[Int,Int]]
```

Or more succinctly by using `traverseU` to infer the types:

```
tenDoubleThrows2.copoint.traverseU(freqSum).exec(Map[Int,Int]())
// Map(10 -> 1, 6 -> 3, 9 -> 1, 7 -> 1, 8 -> 2, 4 -> 2) : scalaz.Id.Id[Map[Int,Int]]
```

Note that because `State[S, A]` is a type alias for `StateT[Id, S, A]`, tenDoubleThrows2 ends up being typed as `Id`. I use `copoint` to turn it back into a `List` type.

In short, it seems the key to use state is to have functions returning a function modifying the state and the actual result value desired... *Disclaimer: I have never used `state` in production code, just trying to get a feel for it.*

**Additional info on @ziggystar comment**

I gave up on trying using `stateT` may be someone else can show if `StateFreq` or `StateRandom` can be augmented to perform the combined computation. What I found instead is that the composition of the two state transformers can be combined like this:

```
def stateBicompose[S, T, A, B](
      f: State[S, A],
      g: (A) => State[T, B]) = State[(S,T), B]{ case (s, t) =>
  val (newS, a) = f(s)
  val (newT, b) = g(a) apply t
  (newS, newT) -> b
}
```

It's predicated on `g` being a one parameter function taking the result of the first state transformer and returning a state transformer. Then the following would work:

```
def diceAndFreqSum = stateBicompose(TwoDice, freqSum)
type St2[x] = State[(Random, Map[Int,Int]), x]
List.fill(10)(diceAndFreqSum).sequence[St2, Int].exec((new Random(1L), Map[Int,Int]()))
```

Comment: Isn't the `State` monad not a "state transformer" in reallity? And as a second question: Is there some nicer way to combine the dice rolling and the summing into one single State monad? How would you do that given the two monads?

Comment: @ziggystar, technically `StateFreq` and `StateRandom` are monads. I don't think `State[S, x]` is a monad transformer since `S` does not need to be a monad. For a nicer way to combine, I'm wondering too. I don't see anything obviously readily available. May be `stateT` could help but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: I didn't write "monad transformer" but "state transformer". The `State[S, x]'` objects don't hold a state but a transformation of the latter. It's just that I think the name could be chosen less confusing. That's nothing about your answer but about Scalaz.

Comment: @ziggystar, I figured out how to leverage `stateT` to combine rolling and summing into a single `StateT` monad! See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7782589/257449. Got stuck towards the end, then I figured out `traverse` eventually.

Comment: "state" in def dice()... ought to be "State".

Comment: @Tvaroh, I was using scalaz 6.x at the time of this question/answer. Are you commenting in the context of scalaz 7.x?

Comment: Is the `!` syntax for `eval()` still valid? `!` is not found in scalaz 7, for me.

Comment: @DavidB., the operator-like syntax seems to have gone away and be replaced by names. `!` is now `eval`; `~>` is now `exec`.

Answer (score 15):

I stumbled on an interesting blog post [*Grok Haskell Monad Transformers*](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/05/grok-haskell-monad-transformers.html) from sigfp that has an example of applying two state monads through a monad transformer. Here is a scalaz translation.

The **first example** shows a `State[Int, _]` monad:

```
val test1 = for {
  a <- init[Int] 
  _ <- modify[Int](_ + 1)
  b <- init[Int]
} yield (a, b)

val go1 = test1 ! 0
// (Int, Int) = (0,1)
```

So I have here an example of using `init` and `modify`. After playing with it a bit, `init[S]` turns out to be really convenient to generate a `State[S,S]` value, but the other thing it allows is to access the state inside the for comprehension. `modify[S]` is a convenient way to transform the state inside the for comprehension. So the example above can be read as:

- `a <- init[Int]`: start with an `Int` state, set it as the value wrapped by the `State[Int, _]` monad and bind it to `a`
- `_ <- modify[Int](_ + 1)`: increment the `Int` state
- `b <- init[Int]`: take the `Int` state and bind it to `b` (same as for `a` but now the state is incremented)
- yield a `State[Int, (Int, Int)]` value using `a` and `b`.

The for comprehension syntax already makes it trivial to work on the `A` side in `State[S, A]`. `init`, `modify`, `put` and `gets` provide some tools to work on the `S` side in `State[S, A]`.

The **second example** in the blog post translates to:

```
val test2 = for {
  a <- init[String]
  _ <- modify[String](_ + "1")
  b <- init[String]
} yield (a, b)

val go2 = test2 ! "0"
// (String, String) = ("0","01")
```

Very much the same explanation as `test1`.

The **third example** is more tricky and I hope there is something simpler that I have yet to discover.

```
type StateString[x] = State[String, x]

val test3 = {
  val stTrans = stateT[StateString, Int, String]{ i => 
    for {
      _ <- init[String]
      _ <- modify[String](_ + "1")
      s <- init[String]
    } yield (i+1, s)
  }
  val initT = stateT[StateString, Int, Int]{ s => (s,s).pure[StateString] }
  for {
    b <- stTrans
    a <- initT
  } yield (a, b)
}

val go3 = test3 ! 0 ! "0"
// (Int, String) = (1,"01")
```

In that code, `stTrans` takes care of the transformation of both states (increment and suffix with `"1"`) as well as pulling out the `String` state. `stateT` allows us to add state transformation on an arbitrary monad `M`. In this case the state is an `Int` that is incremented. If we called `stTrans ! 0` we would end up with `M[String]`. In our example, `M` is `StateString`, so we'll end up with `StateString[String]` which is `State[String, String]`.

The tricky part here is that we want to pull out the `Int` state value out from `stTrans`. This is what `initT` is for. It just creates an object that gives access to the state in a way we can flatMap with `stTrans`.

Edit: Turns out all of that awkwardness can be avoided if we truly reused `test1` and `test2` which conveniently store the wanted states in the `_2` element of their returned tuples:

```
// same as test3:
val test31 = stateT[StateString, Int, (Int, String)]{ i => 
  val (_, a) = test1 ! i
  for (t <- test2) yield (a, (a, t._2))
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is a very small example on how `State` can be used:

Let's define a small "game" where some game units are fighting the boss (who is also a game unit).

```
case class GameUnit(health: Int)
case class Game(score: Int, boss: GameUnit, party: List[GameUnit])


object Game {
  val init = Game(0, GameUnit(100), List(GameUnit(20), GameUnit(10)))
}
```

When the play is on we want to keep track of the game state, so let's define our "actions" in terms of a state monad:

Let's hit the boss hard so he loses 10 from his `health`:

```
def strike : State[Game, Unit] = modify[Game] { s =>
  s.copy(
    boss = s.boss.copy(health = s.boss.health - 10)
  )
}
```

And the boss can strike back! When he does everyone in a party loses 5 `health`.

```
def fireBreath : State[Game, Unit] = modify[Game] { s =>
  val us = s.party
    .map(u => u.copy(health = u.health - 5))
    .filter(_.health > 0)

  s.copy(party = us)
}
```

Now we can *compose* these actions into `play`:

```
def play = for {
  _ <- strike
  _ <- fireBreath
  _ <- fireBreath
  _ <- strike
} yield ()
```

Of course in the real life the play will be more dynamic, but it is food enough for my small example :)

We can run it now to see the final state of the game:

```
val res = play.exec(Game.init)
println(res)

>> Game(0,GameUnit(80),List(GameUnit(10)))
```

So we barely hit the boss and one of the units have died, RIP.

The point here is the *composition*. 
`State` (which is just a function `S => (A, S)`) allows you to define actions that produce results and as well manipulate some state without knowing too much where the state is coming from.
The `Monad` part gives you composition so your actions can be composed:

```
 A => State[S, B] 
 B => State[S, C]
------------------
 A => State[S, C]
```

and so on.

*P.S.* As for differences between `get`, `put` and `modify`:

`modify` can be seen as `get` and `put` together:

```
def modify[S](f: S => S) : State[S, Unit] = for {
  s <- get
  _ <- put(f(s))
} yield ()
```

or simply

```
def modify[S](f: S => S) : State[S, Unit] = get[S].flatMap(s => put(f(s)))
```

So when you use `modify` you conceptually use `get` and `put`, or you can just use them alone.