# scalaz List[StateT].sequence - could not find implicit value for parameter n: scalaz.Applicative

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers, state-monad

I'm trying to figure out how to use `StateT` to combine two `State` state transformers based on a comment on my [Scalaz state monad examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734756/scalaz-state-monad-examples/7734876#7734876) answer.

It seems I'm very close but I got an issue when trying to apply `sequence`.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import java.util.Random

val die = state[Random, Int](r => (r, r.nextInt(6) + 1))

val twoDice = for (d1 <- die; d2 <- die) yield (d1, d2)

def freqSum(dice: (Int, Int)) = state[Map[Int,Int], Int]{ freq =>
  val s = dice._1 + dice._2
  val tuple = s -> (freq.getOrElse(s, 0) + 1)
  (freq + tuple, s)
}

type StateMap[x] = State[Map[Int,Int], x]

val diceAndFreqSum = stateT[StateMap, Random, Int]{ random =>
  val (newRandom, dice) = twoDice apply random
  for (sum <- freqSum(dice)) yield (newRandom, sum)
}
```

So I got as far as having a `StateT[StateMap, Random, Int]` that I can unwrap with initial random and empty map states:

```
val (freq, sum) = diceAndFreqSum ! new Random(1L) apply Map[Int,Int]()
// freq: Map[Int,Int] = Map(9 -> 1)
// sum: Int = 9
```

Now I'd like to generate a list of those `StateT` and use `sequence` so that I can call `list.sequence ! new Random(1L) apply Map[Int,Int]()`. But when trying this I get:

```
type StT[x] = StateT[StateMap, Random, x]
val data: List[StT[Int]] = List.fill(10)(diceAndFreqSum)
data.sequence[StT, Int]

//error: could not find implicit value for parameter n: scalaz.Applicative[StT]
          data.sequence[StT, Int]
                       ^
```

Any idea? I can use some help for the last stretch - assuming it's possible.

Comment: I just don't understand why don't you use Scala's Random.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, Scala has a Random class?! Oh yeah it would work just as well. It's not material to my question so I'll leave `java.util.Random`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah looking at the [scalaz Monad source](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/59dca5cfa5672dbe06f5e05eb46c60b07703bf9c/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Monad.scala#L44), I noticed there was an `implicit def StateTMonad` that confirms that `StateT[M, A, x]` is a monad for type parameter x. Also monads are applicatives, which was confirmed by looking at [the definition of the `Monad`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/59dca5cfa5672dbe06f5e05eb46c60b07703bf9c/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Monad.scala#L14) trait and by poking in the REPL:

```
scala> implicitly[Monad[StT] <:< Applicative[StT]]
res1: <:<[scalaz.Monad[StT],scalaz.Applicative[StT]] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[Monad[StT]]
res2: scalaz.Monad[StT] = scalaz.MonadLow$$anon$1@1cce278
```

So this gave me the idea of defining an implicit `Applicative[StT]` to help the compiler:

```
type StT[x] = StateT[StateMap, Random, x]
implicit val applicativeStT: Applicative[StT] = implicitly[Monad[StT]]
```

That did the trick:

```
val data: List[StT[Int]] = List.fill(10)(diceAndFreqSum)
val (frequencies, sums) =
  data.sequence[StT, Int] ! new Random(1L) apply Map[Int,Int]()

// frequencies: Map[Int,Int] = Map(10 -> 1, 6 -> 3, 9 -> 1, 7 -> 1, 8 -> 2, 4 -> 2)
// sums: List[Int] = List(9, 6, 8, 8, 10, 4, 6, 6, 4, 7)
```