# Trying to understand scalaz state monad

Tags: scala, lift, scalaz, state-monad

I'm trying to start using scalaz in my lift project. For that purpose I'm rewriting some code to meet the style. Consider a code for logging in a user:

```
  def login: CssSel = {
    var password = ""
    def submit() {
      if (doLogin) S.redirectTo("/index")
      else S.error("Wrong password")
    }
    "name=pwd"    #> SHtml.password(password, password = _) &
    "type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(submit)
  }
```

So, this should be rewritten using a state monad somehow. But I just don't get, how.
Trying this:

```
val result = for {
    s       <- init[String]
    pass    <- SHtml.password(s, put(_))
    newPass <- init[String]
    res     <- "name=pwd"    #> pass &
               "type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmit { _ =>
                 if (User.logIn("username", newPass)) S.redirectTo("/index")
                 else S.error("Wrong password")
               }
} yield (newPass, res)
result ! ""
```

**UPD:** Updated example, according to answers.

Any good tutorials/explanations on state monads in scalaz, showing how to use `gets`, `put`, etc?

Comment: Did you have a look at my earlier question/answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734756/scalaz-state-monad-examples

Comment: I’m not sure this is really practical. You can’t just use some state monad and magically get rid of all `var`s in your code. For this to work you must have some means of chaining the state changes which the callback methods of Lift’s `SHtml` do not support. (I think the whole concept of Lift is precisely that you use variables hidden in many closures.) I’d be happy to be proven wrong, though, and see a working example of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: I've never used the Scala state monad. However, I think I see the reason it behaves as you say it does.

> `onSubmit` sees the old `pass`, not the one, I'm `put`'ting

Well, look at what you are doing:

```
... { pass =>
  ... SHtml.password(pass, _ => put(pass))
  ... User.logIn("username", pass)
}
```

Firstly, I don't think you are putting what you think you're putting. Try this instead:

```
... SHTML.password(pass, newPass => put(newPass))
```

Secondly, I don't think you are getting what you think you're getting. I have no clue how Scalaz state monad works, but it should be *something* like this:

```
... User.logIn("username", get())
```

I don't think that you use `pass` to refer to the changing state; `pass` is simply the value that is given to the state computation to begin with, which would explain why `User.logIn("username", pass)` is using the "old" oassword.

Also (though I don't know `SHtml` or what `&` does) I highly doubt this will actually work. It's hard to explain why I think this, but it has something to do with `SHtml` probably not being friendly with constructing state expressions inside of itself, as Debilski commented. `SHtml.password` seems to *expect* you to give it an arbitrarily side-effecting function; this design choice immediately makes it unfriendly to a functional approach for the thing you are attempting to do.

Comment: This is an incomplete and possibly horrible answer. Those that actually know about Lift and scalaz: please vote/comment as appropriate to confirm/deny my conclusions.

Answer (score 2):

The best scalaz examples I have found so far are these:
http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/06/essence-of-iterator-pattern.html?m=1
http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/12/pragmatic-io.html?m=1
And the follow ups.
This example from scalaz examples :)
https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/example/WordCount.scala

In the word count example it counts 3 values and the wordcount value is calculated through using state. I hope this helps.