# scala case class copy implementation

Tags: scala, class, case

I can't find how copy is implemented for case class in scala.

Can I check it somehow?

I though Intellij could point me to implementation, but it doesn't want to jump and I have no idea why :/

Comment: It is generated by scalac, it would look something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6637597/5123895 To actually see it I think you would need to compile and decompile or enable some option in scalac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inspect the scala case class output using `scalac -print ClassName.scala`, as the `copy` is actually a compiler generated method.

Here's a given example:

```
case class Test(s: String, i: Int)
```

This is the output after filtering out noise for `copy`:

```
case class Test extends Object with Product with Serializable {
    private[this] val s: String = _;
    def s(): String = Test.this.s;

    private[this] val i: Int = _;
    def i(): Int = Test.this.i;

    def copy(s: String, i: Int): common.Test = new common.Test(s, i);
    def copy$default$1(): String = Test.this.s();
    def copy$default$2(): Int = Test.this.i();
}
```

Comment: This is a little weird with copy$default$1 and copy$default$2.
I am still not sure what will be called when I would do `Test("a",3).copy(i=5)`

Comment: This is what gets called: `def copy(s: String, i: Int): common.Test = new common.Test(s, i);`

Comment: Okay so it calls some methods of classes we don't see :-)) most acutely, does it avoid reflection?

Comment: @matanster Yes, it is compile time generated.