# What is the best way to build a model/entity in Scala to map with Squeryl?

Tags: scala, model, playframework-2.0, entity, squeryl

I'm very new to Scala, Play Framework and Squeryl. I already understand the concepts of **val** and **var**, but I'm having a hard time on trying to model my entities. As I saw on Squeryl documentation, sometimes they use **var** on **id** and other times use **val**. What is the best approach for id and other values(sometimes they use var/val and other times Option, last one is only for nullable fields on entities)?

**Example 1**

```
    class Playlist(var id: Long, 
                   var name: String, 
                   var path: String) extends KeyedEntity[Long] {
    }
```

**Example 2**

```
class Author(val id: Long, 
              val firstName: String, 
              val lastName: String,
              val email: Option[String]) {
    def this() = this(0,"","",Some(""))        
 }
```

And why sometimes they extend the **KeyedEntity[T]** and sometimes don't?

I really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Squeryl 0.9.5, all entities needed to extend `KeyedEntity[T]` however with 0.9.6 you can provide the `KeyedEntityDef` implicitly. See [this](http://squeryl.org/0.9.6.html) for an example.

`Option[T]` is used when the field can contain null values. When the field is null, `None` is returned.

As for `val` vs. `var` it is exactly as with any other class in Scala. `var` allows for reassignment whereas `val` is, more or less, read-only. If you are going to change values, a lot of people simply make the field a `var`. Alternately, if you are using a case class you can use [`copy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249396/how-to-clone-a-case-class-instance-and-change-just-one-field-in-scala) to create a new object with updated values or you can update the value via reflection.

Comment: Sir, could complete your question with an example of the last topic you mentioned so I can mark your answer as correct? It will help others if they find all information here at once(and it will help me too :] ). Thank you.