# scala call constructor of case class with all fields except one automatically

Tags: scala, constructor, case-class

I am curious how to call the constructor of a scala case class with all of its fields except one (automatically)

```
case class MyClass(a:String, b:Int, c:String)
val myThing = MyClass("a", 1, "b")
```

Something like `MyClass("someOtherValue", myThing.getAllTheValuesExceptOne: _*)` did not yet work for me.

Comment: What is `getAllTheValuesExceptOne` ?

Comment: That is not yet clear to implement that properly ( without writing all the columns) as the class has a lot of fields.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249396/how-to-clone-a-case-class-instance-and-change-just-one-field-in-scala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `copy` method of case classes, it allows to create case class based on others overriding some particular fields.

```
case class MyClass(a:String, b:Int, c:String)
val myThing = MyClass("a", 1, "b")
val myThing2 = myThing.copy(a = "someOtherValue")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a companion object with an apply method.

```
object MyClass {
  def apply(a: String) = {
    new MyClass(a, 1, "AAA")
  }
}
```

Then you can just use

```
val newInstance = MyClass("BBB")
```

Comment: The question is looking for some `automatic` way. This is way too manual approach specially if you have a lot of fields.