# Scala: var to val - redesign

Tags: scala, oop, immutability

In my code base, I want to refractor away from `vars`. The code base structure follows the format:

```
class Animal {
    var name : Option[String] = None
    var owner : Option[String] = None
}

case class Dog(breed: String) extends Animal {
    //Dog logic
}
```

The main reason for this design is that information is not available all at the same time.

So, from `service A`, which deserializes a json, I receive an `Animal` (either `Animal`, `Dog`)

```
val animal = new Animal 
animal.name = "My little animal"
```

and then

```
def update(animal: Animal) : Unit {
    animal match {
        case a : Animal => a.owner = Some("Joe") // call to service B
        case _          => //handle dog
    }
}

update(animal)
```

The question is: How can I redesign it to avoid mutable state in `Animal`?

- Write a `copy` method in `Animal`? There are a bunch of fields, which might generate some boilerplate
- Composition?

Making the two classes `case`?

```
case class Animal (...)
case class Dog(animal: Animal, breed: String)
```

**Edit**

- Animal as a `trait`

I still need a concrete implementation of `Animal`, as I will have `Dogs` and `Animals` (which are really `Animal` and no subtype)

- Problems with copy

The built in case class copy method, does NOT update the values of the `Animal`  class. So defaults values will be used - not what I want. - yes, it is possible to create a case class with all the fields, but is it practical if we have 100+ fields?

Comment: Case classes include a copy method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249396/how-to-clone-a-case-class-instance-and-change-just-one-field-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

You could design this as an ADT (Abstract Data Type) like this:

```
trait Animal {
  def name: Option[String]
  def owner: Option[String]
}

case class Dog(dog: Option[String] = None, owner: Option[String] = None) extends Animal
```

With a case class you have the copy method by default!

Comment: If `Animal` is a `trait` the deserialization fails to create an `Animal`

Comment: I edited by adding the extends clause to Dog case class

Answer (score 0):

A good solution could be to make a trait which specifies `Animal` behavior,

```
sealed trait Animal {
  val name: Option[String]
  val owner: Option[String]
}
```

and then make `case class`es to provide type constructors for your animal instances.

```
case class Dog(name: Option[String], owner: Option[String]) extends Animal
```

Now, `update` (`changeOwner`) will take an `Animal` and return another `Animal` likewise:

```
def changeOwner(animal: Animal): Animal = animal match {
  case Dog(name, owner) => Dog(name, Some("Joe"))
  case _  => animal
}
```

And you will use it as follows:

```
val dog: Animal = Dog(Some("Doggie"), Some("Jack"))
val newDog: Animal = changeOwner(dog)
```

Also, from your code:

```
case a : Animal => a.owner = Some("Joe") // call to service B
```

Be careful with this, as the first `case` of your `match` will take all animals and thus the other cases, for example, your `Dog` case, will be unreachable.

Comment: I edited explaining why `trait Animal` does not suit me and the drawbacks of `copy`