# Idiomatic way to update value in a Map based on previous value

Tags: scala, dictionary, immutability

Let's say I store bank accounts information in an immutable `Map`:

```
val m = Map("Mark" -> 100, "Jonathan" -> 350, "Bob" -> 65)
```

and I want to withdraw, say, $50 from Mark's account. I can do it as follows:

```
val m2 = m + ("Mark" -> (m("Mark") - 50))
```

But this code seems ugly to me. Is there better way to write this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's no `adjust` in the `Map` API, unfortunately. I've sometimes used a function like the following (modeled on Haskell's [`Data.Map.adjust`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map.html), with a different order of arguments):

```
def adjust[A, B](m: Map[A, B], k: A)(f: B => B) = m.updated(k, f(m(k)))
```

Now `adjust(m, "Mark")(_ - 50)` does what you want. You could also use the [pimp-my-library pattern](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) to get the more natural `m.adjust("Mark")(_ - 50)` syntax, if you really wanted something cleaner.

(Note that the short version above throws an exception if `k` isn't in the map, which is different from the Haskell behavior and probably something you'd want to fix in real code.)

Comment: This only works if the key exists in the map. Consider `map.get(k).fold(map)(b => map.updated(k, f(b)))` if you want to ignore a missing key, or an approach that has `f: Option[B] => B` if you want to be able to set the key in its absence.

Comment: @adamnfish: adjust(m, "Mark")(_.getOrElse(0) - 50)

Comment: Very useful - I wish `adjust` were in the standard library! (probably @adamnfish's fold variant..)

Answer (score 15):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, [`Map#updatedWith`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#updatedWith%5BV1%3E:V%5D(key:K)(remappingFunction:Option%5BV%5D=%3EOption%5BV1%5D):CC%5BK,V1%5D) serves this exact purpose:

```
// val map = Map("Mark" -> 100, "Jonathan" -> 350, "Bob" -> 65)
map.updatedWith("Mark") {
  case Some(money) => Some(money - 50)
  case None        => None
}
// Map("Mark" -> 50, "Jonathan" -> 350, "Bob" -> 65)
```

or in a more compact form:

```
map.updatedWith("Mark")(_.map(_ - 50))
```

---

Note that (quoting the [doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#updatedWith%5BV1%3E:V%5D(key:K)(remappingFunction:Option%5BV%5D=%3EOption%5BV1%5D):CC%5BK,V1%5D)) if the remapping function returns `Some(v)`, the mapping is updated with the new value `v`. If the remapping function returns `None`, the mapping is removed (or remains absent if initially absent).

> def updatedWith[V1 >: V](key: K)(remappingFunction: (Option[V]) => Option[V1]): Map[K, V1]

This way, we can elegantly handle cases where the key for which to update the value doesn't exist:

```
Map("Jonathan" -> 350, "Bob" -> 65)
  .updatedWith("Mark")({ case None => Some(0) case Some(v) => Some(v - 50) })
// Map("Jonathan" -> 350, "Bob" -> 65, "Mark" -> 0)
Map("Mark" -> 100, "Jonathan" -> 350, "Bob" -> 65)
  .updatedWith("Mark")({ case None => Some(0) case Some(v) => Some(v - 50) })
// Map("Mark" -> 50, "Jonathan" -> 350, "Bob" -> 65)

Map("Jonathan" -> 350, "Bob" -> 65)
  .updatedWith("Mark")({ case None => None case Some(v) => Some(v - 50) })
// Map("Jonathan" -> 350, "Bob" -> 65)
```

Comment: This seems like the most correct solution in the given scala 2.13+

Answer (score 12):

This could be done with *lenses*. The very idea of a lens is to be able to zoom in on a particular part of an immutable structure, and be able to 1) retrieve the smaller part from a larger structure, or 2) create a new larger structure with a modified smaller part. In this case, what you desire is #2.

Firstly, a simple implementation of `Lens`, stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900307/cleaner-way-to-update-nested-structures), stolen from scalaz:

```
case class Lens[A,B](get: A => B, set: (A,B) => A) extends Function1[A,B] with Immutable {
  def apply(whole: A): B   = get(whole)
  def updated(whole: A, part: B): A = set(whole, part) // like on immutable maps
  def mod(a: A)(f: B => B) = set(a, f(this(a)))
  def compose[C](that: Lens[C,A]) = Lens[C,B](
    c => this(that(c)),
    (c, b) => that.mod(c)(set(_, b))
  )
  def andThen[C](that: Lens[B,C]) = that compose this
}
```

Next, a smart constructor to create a lens from "larger structure" `Map[A,B]` to "smaller part" `Option[B]`. We indicate which "smaller part" we want to look at by providing a particular key. (Inspired by what I remember from [Edward Kmett's presentation on Lenses in Scala](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efv0SQNde5Q)):

```
def containsKey[A,B](k: A) = Lens[Map[A,B], Option[B]](
  get = (m:Map[A,B]) => m.get(k),
  set = (m:Map[A,B], opt: Option[B]) => opt match {
    case None => m - k
    case Some(v) => m + (k -> v)
  }
)
```

Now your code can be written:

```
val m2 = containsKey("Mark").mod(m)(_.map(_ - 50))
```

n.b. I actually changed `mod` from the answer I stole it from so that it takes its inputs curried. This helps to avoid extra type annotations. Also notice `_.map`, because remember, our lens is from `Map[A,B]` to `Option[B]`. This means the map will be unchanged if it does not contain the key `"Mark"`. Otherwise, this solution ends up being very similar to the `adjust` solution presented by Travis.

Answer (score 10):

An [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571709/scala-collections-single-key-multiple-values/10571823#10571823) proposes another alternative, using the `|+|` operator from scalaz

```
val m2 = m |+| Map("Mark" -> -50)
```

The `|+|` operator will sum the values of an existing key, or insert the value under a new key.