# Scala collections, single key multiple values

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary

I have a list of parent keys, each of which could possibly have zero or more associated values. I am not sure which collection to use.

I am using `Map[Int,List[String]]`

I am declaring the Map as

```
var nodes = new HashMap[Int, List[String]]
```

Then I have two methods to handle adding new elements. The first is to add new keys `addNode` and the second is to add new values `addValue`. Initially, the key will not have any values associated with it. Later on, during execution, new values will be associated.

```
def addNode(key: Int) = nodes += (key -> "")

def addValue(key: Int, value: String) = ???
```

I am not sure how to implement `addValues`

### Update:

In response to @oxbow-lakes answer, This is the error I am receiving. Please note that keys need not have values associated with them.

```
scala> var nodes = Map.empty[Int, List[String]]
nodes: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map()

scala> nodes += (1->null)

scala> nodes += (1 -> ("one" :: (nodes get 1 getOrElse Nil)))
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at .<init>(<console>:9)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

### Update 2:

The problem with the code above is the line `nodes += (1->null)` the key should be associated with `Nil` instead. Below is the working code.

```
scala> var nodes = Map.empty[Int, List[String]]
nodes: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map()

scala> nodes += (1->Nil)

scala> nodes += (1 -> ("one" :: (nodes get 1 getOrElse Nil)))

scala> nodes
res27: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map(1 -> List(one))
```

Comment: Actually there is such thing in scala std: [Multimap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.html). Maybe, you'll want to use it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Using MultiMap

You possibly want to use `MultiMap`, which is a mutable collection isomorphic to `Map[K, Set[V]]`. Use as follows:

```
import collection.mutable
val mm = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.Set[String]] with mutable.MultiMap[Int, String]
```

Then you add your nodes:

```
mm addBinding (key, value)
```

### Without MultiMap

The alternative is to stick with immutable values. Assuming you want to avoid using [lenses](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efv0SQNde5Q) (see [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/)), you can add nodes as follows:

```
nodes += (key -> (value :: (nodes get key getOrElse Nil)))
```

Here it is working (in response to your comment):

```
scala> var nodes = Map.empty[Int, List[String]]
nodes: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map()

scala> def addNode(key: Int, value: String) =
     | nodes += (key -> (value :: (nodes get key getOrElse Nil)))
addNode: (key: Int, value: String)Unit

scala> addNode(1, "Hi")

scala> addNode(1, "Bye")

scala> nodes
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map(1 -> List(Bye, Hi))
```

### Using Scalaz

Using the scalaz library, you can realize that this is simply using the `Empty` pattern:

```
nodes += (key -> (value :: ~(nodes get key)))
```

Or you could take advantage of the fact that `Map` is a **monoid**:

```
nodes = nodes |+| Map(key -> List(value))
```

Comment: This line is failing `value :: (nodes get key getOrElse Nil)` I am getting NullPointerException

Comment: I have added an extract from a REPL to show it definitively working. The cause of the NPE must be something else, I'm afraid. Perhaps it warrants a separate question?

Comment: Perhaps in your example, the `nodes` variable is `null`?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @oxbow_lakes' answer, here's a idea for how you could use an `addMap` method that correctly adds two maps together (ie, combining lists for matching keys, adding new lists for new keys):

```
class EnhancedListMap(self: Map[Int,List[String]]) {
  def addMap(other: Map[Int,List[String]]) =
    (this.ungroup ++ enhanceListMap(other).ungroup)
      .groupBy(_._1)
      .mapValues(_.map(_._2))

  def ungroup() =
    self.toList.flatMap{ case (k,vs) => vs.map(k -> _) }
}

implicit def enhanceListMap(self: Map[Int,List[String]]) = new EnhancedListMap(self)
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
val a = Map(1 -> List("a","b"), 2 -> List("c","d"))
val b = Map(2 -> List("e","f"), 3 -> List("g","h"))
a addMap b
//Map(3 -> List(g, h), 1 -> List(a, b), 2 -> List(c, d, e, f))
```

You can include `addNode`, `addValue`, and `addValues` the same way (to `EnhancedListMap` above):

```
  def addNode(key: Int) =
    if(self contains key) self else self + (key -> Nil)

  def addValue(key: Int, value: String) =
    self + (key -> (value :: (self get key getOrElse Nil)))

  def addValues(key: Int, values: List[String]) =
    self + (key -> (values ::: (self get key getOrElse Nil)))
```

And then use them together:

```
var nodes = Map.empty[Int, List[String]]             
// Map()
nodes = nodes.addNode(1)                             
// Map(1 -> List())
nodes = nodes.addValue(1,"a")                        
// Map(1 -> List(a))
nodes = nodes.addValue(2,"b")                        
// Map(1 -> List(a), 2 -> List(b))
nodes = nodes.addValues(2,List("c","d"))             
// Map(1 -> List(a), 2 -> List(c, d, b))
nodes = nodes.addValues(3,List("e","f"))             
// Map(1 -> List(a), 2 -> List(c, d, b), 3 -> List(e, f))
nodes = nodes.addMap(Map(3 -> List("g","h"), 4-> List("i","j")))
// Map(1 -> List(a), 2 -> List(c, d, b), 3 -> List(e, f, g, h), 4 -> List(i, j))
```

Answer (score 0):

I quite like the `getOrElseUpdate` method provided by mutable maps:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._

private val nodes = new HashMap[Int, Buffer[String]]

def addNode(key: Int): Unit =
  nodes.getOrElseUpdate(key, new ArrayBuffer)

def addValue(key: Int, value: String): Unit  =
  nodes.getOrElseUpdate(key, new ArrayBuffer) += value
```