# Idiomatic way to update multiple values in scala.immutable.Map

Tags: scala, dictionary, idioms

I need to update (retrieve and increase) two different values bound to two keys in a map. The two keys can coincide sometimes.
I have the following code for now:

```
// val map: Map[Int, Int]
// val key1, key2: Int
if (key1 == key2) {
  tailRecFunction(someArg, map 
    + Tuple2(key1, 2 + map.getOrElse(key1, 0)))
} else {
  tailRecFunction(someArg, map 
    + Tuple2(key1, 1 + map.getOrElse(key1, 0))
    + Tuple2(key2, 1 + map.getOrElse(key2, 0)))
}
```

As you can see, if you use the `else` block when `key1 == key2`, then the value at `key1 == key2` will incorrectly be increased by `1` instead of `2` ---  the second tuple erroneously updates the original value, rather than the value applied by the first tuple.
**Is there a cleaner way to write this?**

Comment: why is this downvoted? please specify a reason so I know where I made the mistake!

Comment: this question should be linked to [Idiomatic way to update value in a Map based on previous value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9003874/3041008)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you can simplify the map to return `0` when no key is present:

```
val map0 = Map.empty[Int, Int] withDefaultValue 0
```

Then you can safely call `map(key)` instead of `map.getOrElse(key, 0)`.

Second, you can use the arrow-association syntax to create `Tuple2` instances. I.e. `key -> value` instead of `Tuple2(key, value)`.

Third, I would not introduce the `if ... then ... else` at all. Just update the map for each key successively:

```
def addKey(map: Map[Int, Int], key: Int) = map + (key -> (map(key) + 1))

val map1 = addKey(map0, key1)
val map2 = addKey(map1, key2)
tailRecFunction(someArg, map2)
```

Comment: Thanks, great suggestions! (Ad3): I can still avoid a val definition with `val newMap = addKey(addKey(oldMap, key1), key2)`

Comment: I would strongly recommend not using `withDefaultValue` in this way, especially with immutable maps. This is one of the warts in scala's collection libraries. See this debate amongst the compiler developers https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/R4fTU_5XVZs/discussion. For example, https://gist.github.com/drstevens/9201268

Comment: @drstevens In the case of histograms and counting elements, `withDefaultValue(0)` is perfectly sensible IMO, but yes you should be careful when you transform the map.

Comment: Another [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5831667/3041008) suggests using the `~` operator from the __ScalaZ__ library, which avoids the dangers of `withDefaultValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Another [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571823/3041008) suggests using the **Monoid** characteristics of Map (ScalaZ):

```
tailRecFunction(someArg, map |+| Map(key1 -> 1) |+| Map(key2 -> 1))
```

The `|+|` operator will sum values that belong to the same key.

Comment: Similar principle as in [Best way to merge two maps and sum the values of same key?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7076128/3041008)