# Scala reduce Sequence of Map to a Map with max value for each key

Tags: scala, dictionary, reduce

I have a Seq of Map like this:

```
Seq(
  Map("k1" -> 1),
  Map("k1" -> 2),
  Map("k2" -> 3),
  Map("k2" -> 4)
)
```

I want to reduce to a single map that has values equals to the Max of each `(key,value)`

Expected result:

```
Seq(
  Map("k1" -> 2),
  Map("k2" -> 4)
)
```

How can I reduce the sequence of map?

Comment: Are they all singleton maps?

Comment: they are immutable maps

Comment: `Map("k1",1)` is not valid syntax. Do you have tuples in mind `"k1" -> 1`?

Comment: yes I am sorry @MarioGalic

Comment: Are you sure your expected result is a sequence of maps? Maybe you want just a single map? Also, it is weird that your input is a sequence of singleton maps, maybe you would rather have a sequence of tuples?

Answer (score 2):

On `2.13` you can do this:

```
def mergeMapsWithMax[K, V : Ordering](data: IterableOnce[Map[K, V]]): Map[K, V] =
  data
    .iterator
    .flatten
    .toList
    .groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(Ordering[V].max)
```

Which you can use use like this:

```
val data = Seq(
  Map("k1" -> 1),
  Map("k1" -> 2),
  Map("k2" -> 3),
  Map("k2" -> 4)
)
// data: Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = List(Map(k1 -> 1), Map(k1 -> 2), Map(k2 -> 3), Map(k2 -> 4))


mergeMapsWithMax(data)
// res: Map[String,Int] = Map(k1 -> 2, k2 -> 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you reconsider to using list of tuples instead of sequence of maps

```
val tuples = List(
  ("k1", 1),
  ("k1", 2),
  ("k2", 3),
  ("k2", 4)
)
```

try `foldLeft` like so

```
tuples.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) { case (acc, t @ (key, value)) =>
  acc.get(key) match {
    case Some(oldValue) => if (oldValue >= value) acc else acc + t
    case None => acc + t
  }
}
// val res0: Map[String,Int] = Map(k1 -> 2, k2 -> 4)
```

or using [`updatedWith`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55405528/5205022)

```
tuples.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) { case (acc, t @ (key, value)) =>
  acc.updatedWith(key) {
    case Some(oldValue) => Some(math.max(oldValue, value))
    case None => Some(value)
  }
}
// val res1: Map[String,Int] = Map(k1 -> 2, k2 -> 4)
```

This should be rather [performant](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/performance-characteristics.html) because we are single-passing thorough the list and `Map`'s lookup/add has by default effectively constant time.

Answer (score 1):

```scala
Seq(Map("k1" -> 1), Map("k1" -> 2), Map("k2" -> 3), Map("k2" -> 4))
  .reduce { (m1, m2) =>
    (m1.toSeq ++ m2.toSeq).groupBy(_._1).map {
      case (k, values) => k -> values.map(_._2).max
    }
  }
```

Produces

```
Map(k2 -> 4, k1 -> 2)
```

```html
<script src="https://scastie.scala-lang.org/3aqyPILyRAS1tUagYcpq7w.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have cannot resolve .map on values "values.map(_._2).max"

Comment: This is strange. The scastie code works fine. What does compiler tell you?

Answer (score 0):

If you're determined to use maps and not tuples, use this short (but not necessarily efficient) version:

```
mapSeq.flatMap(_.toList).groupBy(_._1).map(_._2.max)
```

Otherwise, you can use

```
tupleSeq.groupBy(_._1).map(_._2.max)
```