# Transforming json with lift

Tags: json, scala, lift

how easily i can transform data ? 
I can searching data which interesting me, f. ex:

```
json \\ fieldName1 \\ fieldName2 \\ fieldName3
```

But how i can of this search modify value? f. ex

```
json transform{
  case JField(x,y) => JField(x, z)
}
```

Comment: edit: I try: getting fields from query and then for each Jfield call method transform where i checked if current field is field from query. But this is very ugly

Comment: Could you use ``extract`` (cf. the lift-json docs https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/, section "Extracting values") in order to transform the json AST into a list of case classes, and then use the usual collection methods such as ``filter`` and ``map`` in order to do the transformation?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/), you get exactly what you want :

```
scala> import net.liftweb.json._
scala> import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._

scala> val json = 
  ("person" ->
    ("name" -> "Joe") ~
    ("age" -> 35) ~
    ("spouse" -> 
      ("person" -> 
        ("name" -> "Marilyn") ~
        ("age" -> 33)
      )
    )
  )
scala> json transform {
         case JField("name", JString(s)) => JField("NAME", JString(s.toUpperCase))
       }
res8: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List(JField(person,JObject(List(
JField(NAME,JString(JOE)), JField(age,JInt(35)), JField(spouse,JObject(List(
JField(person,JObject(List(JField(NAME,JString(MARILYN)), JField(age,JInt(33)))))))))))))
```

The above codes are copied from the linked page.

If you don't use lift-json, you may take a look at [kiama](https://code.google.com/p/kiama/), as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3900498/448141).

Comment: `transform` is now called `transformField`