# Scala Option object inside another Option object

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, scala-option

I have a model, which has some Option fields, which contain another Option fields. For example:

```
case class First(second: Option[Second], name: Option[String])
case class Second(third: Option[Third], title: Option[String])
case class Third(numberOfSmth: Option[Int])
```

I'm receiving this data from external JSON's and sometimes this data may contain null's, that was the reason of such model design.

So the question is: what is the best way to get a deepest field?

```
First.get.second.get.third.get.numberOfSmth.get
```

Above method looks really ugly and it may cause exception if one of the objects will be None. I was looking in to Scalaz lib, but didn't figure out a better way to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a note but the flatMap woun't work as given below several times. It should be `First.second.flatMap(_.third.flatMap(_.numberOfSmth)).get` and is still might throw and exception

Comment: Indeed, thanks. Thanks everyone for your answers, I've found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution is to use `Option.map` and `Option.flatMap`:

```
First.flatMap(_.second.flatMap(_.third.map(_.numberOfSmth)))
```

Or the equivalent (see the **update** at the end of this answer):

```
First flatMap(_.second) flatMap(_.third) map(_.numberOfSmth)
```

This returns an `Option[Int]` (provided that `numberOfSmth` returns an `Int`). If any of the options in the call chain is `None`,  the result will be `None`, otherwise it will be `Some(count)` where `count` is the value returned by `numberOfSmth`.

Of course this can get ugly very fast. For this reason scala supports *for comprehensions* as a syntactic sugar. The above can be rewritten as:

```
for { 
  first <- First
  second <- first .second
  third <- second.third
} third.numberOfSmth
```

Which is arguably nicer (especially if you are not yet used to seeing `map`/`flatMap` everywhere, as will certainly be the case after a while using scala), and generates the exact same code under the hood.

For more background, you may check this other question: [What is Scala's yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/can-someone-explain-scalas-yield)

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to Ben James for pointing out that flatMap is associative. In other words `x flatMap(y flatMap z)))` is the same as `x flatMap y flatMap z`. While the latter is usually not shorter, it has the advantage of avoiding any nesting, which is easier to follow.

Here is some illustration in the REPL (the 4 styles are equivalent, with the first two using flatMap nesting, the other two using flat chains of flatMap):

```
scala> val l = Some(1,Some(2,Some(3,"aze")))
l: Some[(Int, Some[(Int, Some[(Int, String)])])] = Some((1,Some((2,Some((3,aze))))))
scala> l.flatMap(_._2.flatMap(_._2.map(_._2)))
res22: Option[String] = Some(aze)
scala> l flatMap(_._2 flatMap(_._2 map(_._2)))
res23: Option[String] = Some(aze)
scala> l flatMap(_._2) flatMap(_._2) map(_._2)
res24: Option[String] = Some(aze)
scala> l.flatMap(_._2).flatMap(_._2).map(_._2)
res25: Option[String] = Some(aze)
```

Comment: You don't need to use ugly nesting: because of the associativity of `flatMap`, `a flatMap (b flatMap c)` is equivalent to `a flatMap b flatMap c`

Comment: Thanks, you are very right. I usually nest them because this mimics the actual structure of what is mappped/flatMapped over (which **is** nested, as in this case). But it's true that it is more readable as a flat chain of `flatMap`.

Comment: Note that not nesting flatMaps has the disadvantage of not being able to use a lambda parameter in nested lambda expressions, so although it works in this case I would not recommend it general. It's also slower and creates more function objects.

Comment: I can only agree. As for people that wonder why the nested version is faster and creates fewer function objects (on average), it is because as soon as we encounter a `None`, the chain stops and so we don't get to (needlessly) create the function objects further down the chain. With flat chains of `flatMap`'s, all the `flatMap`s are always executed even past the point we encounter a `None`, so this is wasted processing plus needless creation of function objects (those past the point we encountered a `None`). So this is good to know, even if this should not matter much, most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for REPL example! It's nice to be able to play with it.

Answer (score 10):

There is no need for scalaz:

```
for { 
  first  <- yourFirst
  second <- f.second
  third  <- second.third
  number <- third.numberOfSmth
} yield number
```

Alternatively you can use nested flatMaps

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by chaining calls to `flatMap`:

```
def getN(first: Option[First]): Option[Int] =
  first flatMap (_.second) flatMap (_.third) flatMap (_.numberOfSmth)
```

You can also do this with a for-comprehension, but it's more verbose as it forces you to name each intermediate value:

```
def getN(first: Option[First]): Option[Int] =
  for {
    f <- first
    s <- f.second
    t <- s.third
    n <- t.numberOfSmth
  } yield n
```

Answer (score 1):

*I think it is an overkill for your problem but just as a general reference:*

This nested access problem is addressed by a concept called Lenses. They provide a nice mechanism to access nested data types by simple composition. As introduction you might want to check for instance [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5597750/1804173) or [this tutorial](https://blog.stackmob.com/2012/02/an-introduction-to-lenses-in-scalaz/). The question whether it makes sense to use Lenses in your case is whether you also have to perform a lot of updates in you nested option structure (note: *update* not in the mutable sense, but returning a new modified but immutable instance). Without Lenses this leads to lengthy nested case class `copy` code. If you do not have to update at all, I would stick to [om-nom-nom's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111652/1804173).

Comment: @Downvoter: Would you mind to explain the downvote? Given the OP has to update this nested structure a lot, I think should be allowed to point the OP to the concept of Lenses as alternative solution?