# Update deeply nested case class with Options

Tags: scala, lenses, monocle-scala

I have a 3-level nested case class model with a bunch of options that represents some data in a database. It's essentially:

```
case class User(settings: Option[Settings])
case class Settings(keys: Option[List[KeySet]])
case class KeySet(privateKey: String, publicKey: String)
```

I understand how to get deeply nested fields out of this using some for comprehension or chains of `flatMap` ([Scala Option object inside another Option object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111565/scala-option-object-inside-another-option-object))  and I also understand how to update it using a lens library, but I want to figure out how to update the fields even if some stuff in the tree is `None` and automatically make `Some`s of those if they don't exist yet.

For example, how would I handle the case where I want to add to the `keys` List but the user hasn't yet set any `settings`? Is it possible to, in some sense, automatically create a `Some(settings)` field and also a `Some(keys)` field?

I have an idea of how to do it with a lot of pattern matching, but this seems wrong because of 1. rightward drift of code and 2. not using `map` or `flatMap` very much with the options.

Is this possible using a lens library on its own? I read here that it might not be possible: https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle/issues/215 as in the case of Monocle it can't update an `Option` that is a `None`. Maybe I need to think about the problem another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you use `Option[List[KeySet]]`. Is there an important distinction between `None` and an empty `List`?

In any case, I find `fold` to be a handy tool when working with Options.

```
def updateUser(u :User, ks :KeySet) :User = {
  u.copy(settings =
    Some(u.settings.fold(Settings(Some(ks::Nil))) (stngs =>
      stngs.copy(keys = Some(stngs.keys.fold(ks::Nil) (ks::_))))))
}

val pat = updateUser(User(None), KeySet("a","b"))
//pat: User = User(Some(Settings(Some(List(KeySet(a,b))))))

val upat = updateUser(pat, KeySet("c","d"))
//upat: User = User(Some(Settings(Some(List(KeySet(c,d), KeySet(a,b))))))
```