# example uses scalaz.Lens's modf, modp and xmap

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, functor, scalaz

There are number of great tutorials and posts out there covering the more straightforward of Lens's methods, e.g. [Cleaner way to update nested structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900307/cleaner-way-to-update-nested-structures); can anyone provide example uses for these three other methods? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Scalaz7 lens examples are a WIP. You need to ask this question of [the Scalaz Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/scalaz). Before you ask, try these examples here and watch Emmett's videos.

- [Using lenses with Scalaz 7](http://www.monadzoo.com/blog/2012/11/18/using-lenses-with-scalaz-7/)
- [Emmett's videos on Lenses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efv0SQNde5Q&feature=relmfu)

Look at the source code again. What can you puzzle out from this?

```
 def xmapbA[X, A >: A2 <: A1](b: Bijection[A, X]): LensFamily[X, X, B1, B2] =
    xmapA(b to _)(b from _)

  def xmapB[X1, X2](f: B1 => X1)(g: X2 => B2): LensFamily[A1, A2, X1, X2] =
    lensFamily(a => run(a).xmap(f)(g))

  def xmapbB[X, B >: B1 <: B2](b: Bijection[B, X]): LensFamily[A1, A2, X, X] =
    xmapB(b to _)(b from _)


  /** Modify the value viewed through the lens, returning a functor `X` full of results. */
  def modf[X[+_]](f: B1 => X[B2], a: A1)(implicit XF: Functor[X]): X[A2] = {
    val c = run(a)
    XF.map(f(c.pos))(c put _)
  }
```

Sorry for the minimal help. I can just point at whom to ask and what you need to know before you ask.

Comment: Thanks for the references, Raahul.