# How to handle objects that are value in map?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10

Lets say there is a class

```
case class User(id: Long, firstName: String, surName: String, password: String)
```

and a map

```
var userMap = Map(
    1 -> User(1, "firstName1", "surName1", "1111"),
    2 -> User(2, "firstName2", "surName2", "2222"),
    3 -> User(3, "firstName3", "surName3", "3333")
)
```

by doing that

```
userMap find { case (a,b) => b == (1, "firstName1", "surName1", "1111") } isDefined
```

I can find if there is that value or not, but

how can I find if there is, for instance, surName1 in the userMap, if there is to change it and return me true or false if there is no such a surname?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `b == User(1, "firstName1", "surName1", "1111")`?

Comment: You may want a lens: look at the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900307/cleaner-way-to-update-nested-structures).

Comment: @WeaponsGrade Possibly more advanced than the OP is quite ready for, but definitely something anybody should be interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Almost what you have now except for matching on all properties of the value just explicitly match on the `surName` property.

```
userMap.find{case (i, user) => user.surName == "surName1"}.isDefined
res0: Boolean = true

scala> userMap.find{case (i, user) => user.surName == "foo"}.isDefined
res1: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using find ... isDefined you would be better to opt to exists if you want to just check existence of said item:

```
userMap exists { 
   case (_, user) => user == User(1, "firstName1", "surName1", "1111") 
}
```

Next, if you want to

> how can I find if there is, for instance, surName1 in the userMap, if there is to change it and return me true or false if there is no such a surname

There is not much to change to you code:

```
val found = userMap find { case (k,user) => user == User(_, _, "surName1", _) } 
// or with field access as @brian showed
found.foreach { case (key, value) => // do update with userMap by found key } 
found.isDefined
```

Comment: Why not userMap.values.exists for the first?

Comment: @itsbruce yes, it could be `userMap.values.exists` as well

Answer (score 0):

```
scala>  userMap.values.exists{ case User(_, surName1, _, _ ) => true }
res1: Boolean = true
```

But if you're going to make a change, don't check for true then do it.  That's imperative non-scala way of thinking.  Here's a mildly evil way of doing that:

```
var changed = false
userMap map { x => x match {
    case (n, User(i, f, "surName1", p)) => {
      changed = true
      (n, User(i, f, "Appleyard", p))
    }
    case _ => x
  }
}
```

What this does is return a copy of userMap (because your userMap is probably immutable unless you specified a mutable map), with any "surName1" users changed to "Appleyards".  If any matching users were found, "changed" will be set to true as a side-effect.  I call this mildly evil because it uses side effects.  Mind you, there's a very simple way of avoiding the side-effect...

```
scala> newMap = userMap  map { x => x match {
    case (n, User(i, f, "surName1", p)) => {
      (n, User(i, f, "Appleyard", p))
    }
    case _ => x
  }
}

scala> newMap == userMap
res2: Boolean = false
```

Now here's something more formal

```
def surnameA2B(oldName: String, newName: String, m: Map[Int,User]): (Int, Map[Int,User]) = {
  val changed = m collect {
    case (n, User(i, f, s, p)) if s == oldName =>
      (n, User(i, f, newName, p))
  }
  (changed.size, m ++ changed)
}

surnameA2B("surName1", "Appleyard", userMap)
res1: (Int, Map[Int,User]) = (1,Map(1 -> User(1,firstName1,Appleyard,1111), 2 -> User(2,firstName2,surName2,2222), 3 -> User(3,firstName3,surName3,3333)))
```

Given a name to match, a replacement name and a usermap, it returns a count of the changed users and a new usermap with the changes in place.  0 means no changes, so you can derive your boolean just by testing if the count is 0 or not.

Checking for a condition, then acting if it is true, then setting a condition based on the actions is a very imperative, non-Scala way of doing things.  In fact, it is rarely necessary to check if a condition is true, when you can chain functions so that A will naturally happen if B completed (and for each relevant iteration of B, if necessary.  Scala makes it easy to try this approach and it results in cleaner code.