# Scala Classes and Objects

Tags: scala

In Scala if I create a class like this:

```
class Time(var hour: Int) {
  if (hour < 0) hour = 0
}
```

I can comfortably create a new object using
`x = new Time(4)`

If I need to get the time for the `x` object I can do
`x.hour` and I get back `res5: Int = 4` which is cool. But considering I want to change the `hour` variable of `x` is doing `x.hour = 5` enough? I think so. Is there another way to do this.

My main question is. How would I create another object, if i didn't want to use the `new` keyword?

Comment: Note that your code doesn't prevent you from setting a negative hour: `val x = new Time(0); x.hour = -3` will still set `hour` to `-3`.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, you can use case classes, but case class with var constructor parameter is usually a bad choice, as it meant to be immutable. To simulate changes you can use auto-generated `copy` method (it became more useful, if you have multiple parameters).

```
scala> case class Time(hour: Int) { require(hour > 0) }
defined class Time

scala> Time(-1)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
...

scala> val t1 = Time(1)
t1: Time = Time(1)

scala> val t2 = t1.copy(hour = 2)
t2: Time = Time(2)
```

For more complex sample, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211022/updating-immutable-objects).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case class if you want to omit the `new` keyword:

```
case class Time(var hour: Int) {
  if (hour < 0) hour = 0
}

val today = Time(-1)      //> today  : Time = Time(0)
```

Case classes can also be used in pattern matching with `case` statements.

```
today match {
  case Time(0) => "foo"
  case Time(1) => "bar"
}  //> res0: String = foo
```

Here is another SO post that talks about case classes:  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312881/what-is-the-difference-between-scalas-case-class-and-class)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create another object without directly or indirectly using the `new` keyword. Case classes, seems to allow that:

```
case class Person(name: String)
val p1 = Person("John")
```

However, that case class translates into something like this:

```
class Person(val name: String) {
  override def equals(other: AnyRef): Boolean = ???
  override def hashCode: Int = ???
  override def toString: String = s"Person($name)"
}
object Person {
  def apply(name: String) = new Person(name)
  def unapply(person: Person): Option[String] = ???
}
val p1 = Person.apply("John")
```

So there's an implicit `new` there.

Answer (score 0):

First question: Yes. Run `scala` in a terminal and you'll get the REPL, in which you can try out stuff like this yourself.

```
scala> class Time(var hour: Int) {
     |   if (hour < 0) hour = 0
     | }
defined class Time

scala> val x = new Time(4)
x: Time = Time@bcc8d5

scala> x.hour = 5
x.hour: Int = 5

scala> x.hour
res0: Int = 5
```

Second question: It's a little unclear what you're asking for, but I think it's this:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Time(var hour: Int) {
  if (hour < 0) hour = 0
}
object Time {
  def apply(hour: Int): Time = new Time(hour)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Time
defined module Time

scala> val y = Time(7)
y: Time = Time@7359fe

scala> y.hour
res1: Int = 7
```